# Require image inside v-html in Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, tiptap

I'm using Tiptap editor to write content, and then I attach data generated by it via `v-html` directive.

I understand that v-html can process images that have absolute source like 'https://something/file.jpg', but I need to require an image that goes through Webpack and gets a hash in its name. And requiring images seems not to be working inside v-html. Did someone solve such a problem?

upd
The code is the following:

```
<div v-html="someData"></div>
```

someData comes as response to async request and it looks like this:

```
<p> kjfdkf </p> <p> kfdfk </p> <div> kdfjdkf </div>
```

This is a standard output of text editor. In order not to show it with tags I pass it to `v-html`. The question is how to address images going through webpack. I don't have a clue.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Require the image beforehand and pass the raw data thru v-html

Comment: Images are in-between text, and text must go through v-html so I don't quite see how to split text and images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understood your question correctly, but considering you have an HTML string like this:

```html
<p> kjfdkf </p>
<img src="PATH" />
<p> kfdfk </p> 
<img src="PATH" /> 
<div> kdfjdkf </div>
```

...with random image elements inside, you could probably parse the HTML to change the sources of the image elements to their raw data instead of the current relative paths.

`DOMParser` seems like the easiest option to parse the HTML, as you can parse it in one line:

```js
let el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.html, "text/html");
```

Then just find all image elements:

```js
let imgs = el.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

...change their sources to the raw forms:

```js
imgs.forEach((img) => (img.src = require(img.src)));
```

...select the body of `el` (since that's where your HTML is in):

```js
let body = el.body;
```

...and return its innerHTML:

```js
return body.innerHTML;
```

You can wrap this all in a computed property:

```js
computed: {
  processedHtml() {
    let el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.html, "text/html"),
      imgs = el.getElementsByTagName("img");
    imgs.forEach((img) => (img.src = require(img.src)));
    let body = el.body;
    return body.innerHTML;
  },
}
```

Here's the full code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-html="processedHtml"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      html: `<p> kjfdkf </p><img src="PATH" /> <p> kfdfk </p> <img src="PATH" /> <div> kdfjdkf </div>`,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    processedHtml() {
      let el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.html, "text/html"),
        imgs = el.getElementsByTagName("img");
      imgs.forEach((img) => (img.src = require(img.src)));
      let body = el.body;
      return body.innerHTML;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you move the images to your `public` directory, their names won't be modified by webpack, so you could possibly avoid all this.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a bit to marsnebulasoup's answer

First, when we save image source in Tiptap editor if I type @/assets/img/someImg.jpg, it saves it as 'http://localhost:8080/@/assets/img/someImg.jpg', which is not exactly what I want. So I added a line to extract image name:

```
const src = img.src.slice(img.src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

And second `require` does not accept a variable, so I didn't manage to do

```
imgs.forEach((img) => (img.src = require(img.src)));
```

I had to do it this way:

```
const imgSrc = require(`@/assets/img/${src}`);
img.src = imgSrc;
```